# I am only able to access ID of apex class from c# method

Tags: c#, salesforce, apex

Methods and properties are visible while debugging but not in code.Please suggest

```
    public string CheckApexClassNameOrg(SforceServiceService refService, string cname)
    {

        QueryResult queryResult = new QueryResult();
        queryResult = refService.query("Select Id,Name,SymbolTable,body from ApexClass where Name = '" + cname.Trim() + "'");
        if (queryResult.size == 1)
        {
            sObject[] records = queryResult.records;
            string Id = queryResult.records[0].Id.ToString();
            return Id;
        }
        else
            return "Not Available";
    }
```

Comment: Can you give us more information please? What do you mean by "not visible in code"?

Comment: Intellisense isn't always perfect. But what you can type in Debug-Watch you can also type in the Code window. Sometimes it requires casts. Debug knows the real type of your object, your Code only knows the type of the variable holding an object.

Comment: I mean in intellisense

Comment: string name= queryResult.records[0].Name.ToString();

Comment: I get this message: 
Error CS1061 'sObject' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'sObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) GenieAPI D:\Genie-Sprint2.3\GenieAPI\Repository\ClassRepo.cs 94 Active

Comment: What is `sObject`?  Does it have a `Name` property?

Comment: sObject is salesforce object which I am trying to access in c# code.While debugging it shows that property but not in intellisense

Comment: `sObject` is the base class for the objects runtime type.  If you want to access that property, you need to cast it to the appropriate type.  We don't know what that might be.

Answer (score 0):

@Holger is right. To see in intellisense suggestion, you have to cast your object to right class.
If you don't know right class, you can learn from debug. Because run-time CLR knows all of system but compiler-time can't understand and reach all types. You can imagine this like reflection. Same logic is valid.

Comment: What can be done in this case ? I need to get the remaining properties

Comment: There is "Id" column in two class (QueryResult  and APEXClass)  so you can set Id. But other properties don't contains in QueryResult. To see that you have to cast queryResult to APEXClass.